# Is this function Lipschitz and therefore has a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I'm struggling to understand if the differential equation $y'=ye^x$ with initial value $y(0)=1$ or rather the $f(x,y)= ye^x$ part is Lipschitz, as from that it would follow that it has a unique solution. I have already solved the IVP, which gave me $y(x)=e^{e^x-1}$, but I don't think this answers whether it has a unique solution. Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y(x)=e^{e^x}$ is a solution of the differential equation, but not a solution of the IVP, since $y(0)=e \ne 1.$

The correct solution of the IVP is given by $ y(x)=\frac{1}{e}e^{e^x}$.

In order to show that this is the unique solution of the IVP, you need no "Lipschitz":

Asumme that $z$ is also a solution of the IVP and consider the function $h:= y/z.$

Now show that $h'=0$ on $ \mathbb R.$ Hence $h$ is constant. Since $h(0)=1$, we get $h=1,$ thus $z=y.$

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add $-1$. And thanks for the answer. But doesn't the fact that $\partial_y (ye^x)= e^x$ which is not smaller than any Lipschitz constant speak against that? Sorry if this is silly, I'm just trying to understand the Lipschitz notion that we need to use in class...

Comment: $f $ is locally Lipschitz, since $ |f(x,y)−f(x,z)|=e^x|y−z|.$